# how do two end devices know if the other is in a different subnet or not?

Tags: networking

I want to know how two devices on different subnets know that the other is not in the same subnet 
[network for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrJ3B.png) and would the destination IP address be the default gateway if they were to send something to each other?

Comment: They know their own netmasks, and any IP address that does match it isn't in this subnet and has to be reached via the gateway.

Comment: when they send to the default gateway is the destination ip address that of the gateway or the destination itself?

Comment: The destination itself. They send to the gateway via a level 2 address, e.g. MAC.

Comment: i also had an issue where i try pinging PC3 from PC0 but it wouldnt reach even though i have the default gateways set up and everything it says host unreachable any reason why those 2 cannot communicate?